# Keep an iOS provisioning profile app from expiring

Tags: ios, ipad, jailbreak, appstore-approval, ios-provisioning

I have developed an iPad app very specific to my needs, it is tailored just for me and therefore isn't applicable to be submitted to the app store. Every few months I can't get into my app because the provisioning profile has expired.

Is there an easy way (besides jailbreaking the device, or submitted it to Apple) that I can use the app indefinitely without having to generate a new provisioning profile every few months?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ad Hoc profiles seem to have a long lifetime. So instead using a Dev Profile, an Ad Hoc profile might serve your needs better. My latest Ad Hoc profile created in May expires together with my current certificate next year.

Comment: but when it expires then, do users get a notice? I need to define the update process for Enterprise (Ad-Hoc) Apps and they seem to expire silently without being able to open them then.

Comment: @spankmaster79 iOS issues an alert when a provisioning Profile is about to expire. It is shown some days before expiration and offers to show the profile or to be reminded later again.

Answer (score 0):

Nope. Provisioning is working exactly as it's designed to work in this case.